# Not redirecting when adding WWW before host name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect users from HTTP to HTTPS using the following:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

It is working fine if I try to hit URL as **example.com**: it redirects to **https:example.com** which is fine. But when I try to hit the URL as **www.example.com**, then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>    ServerName example.com
>    RewriteEngine on
>    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> It is working fine if I try to hit URL as example.com, it redirects to
>   https:example.com which is fine, but when I try to hit the URL as
>   www.example.com then it doesn't work.

It is not supposed to work. Your virtual name is `example.com`, **not** `www.example.com`. So when you hit `www.example.com`, that particular virtualhost is not involved, and some other configuration directive activates instead (possibly, the default).

Try adding an alias:

```
ServerName    example.com
ServerAlias   www.example.com
```

Comment: there is one question, is there any way to make it not work for some specific directory, like if i try to access www.example.com/ads then it should not work. It will be really appreciated if you help me out. :)

Comment: You can place another RewriteRule before the catch-all rule, and mark it as last. Or you can use `RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/ads"` or something like that to prepend to your existing rule.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```